# Best practice to reload a function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have corrected the code and it works, it is good practice to do it that way?

```
$(document).on("click", ".upvotes", function datos(){

    $.post('/post/', function(data){

            console.log(data);
            $('.vote_count').html(data.number);
            setTimeout(function(data){ 
                /* Do stuff with data variable in here */ 
                console.log(data);
                datos();
                //$('.vote_count').html();
            }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You want to repeat the request again when it finishes?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish (i.e. what *should* be happening in the `setTimeout()`? What errors, if any, are you seeing in your console? What output are you seeing in your console as a result of `console.log(data)`? Need a lot more detail in this question.

Comment: The proper syntax is `setTimeout(function(){ /* code here */ },1000);`

Comment: i got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (", I'm trying to repeat the instruction" $.post('/post/', function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('.vote_count').html(data.number);", thanks

Comment: Your syntax is jacked: `setTimeout(function(data) { //dostuff },1000);` you're missing a paren. EDIT: didn't see your post @KostasX

Comment: @Capitalize please update your question with the error you're getting and and what you're trying to accomplish. Nobody wants to read through a series of comments to piece together what you're asking.

Comment: @Capitalize please don't ever "correct the code" in your initial question. Now nobody knows what in the world the initial problem actually was because your question now has correct code and what you're asking is completely different from what you/we were initially trying to solve. If you've figured out a solution to your problem, you need to provide it as an *answer*. To answer what is, apparently, now your question, no, it's not best practice to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here, I have been reading the rules, but I forgot that part, there is a way to restore the old code?

Comment: @Capitalize you'd just have to re-edit the question. But at this point, I'd leave it as is and just keep this in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be rewritten like this:

```
var timer;

$(document).on("click", ".upvotes", function(){

    $.post('/post/', function(data){

            console.log(data);
            $('.vote_count').html(data.number);
            timer = setTimeout(function(data){ 
                /* Do stuff with data variable in here */ 
            }, 1000);

    });

});

$(".another-button").on("click", function(){

    // This will stop the setTimeout that was initialized in the button click above
    clearTimeout(timer);

});
```

Comment: Hello, I try to call the same function like a loop while (true), but I have to repeat the same code in, there is a better practice?

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day.

Comment: yes, just as I wanted, now I need to turn it off with another button!!

Comment: You store your setTimeout in a variable and use **clearTimeout** to clear it using the variable passed as the function's first parameter. I've edited the code above to illustrate the point.

Comment: @Capitalize are you wanting the `$.post()` to run indefinitely, run indefinitely until someone ends it, a certain number of times, only repeat once, etc.?

Comment: Thank you @ KostasX, there are no problems with global variables? , @jeffdill2 yes, I want to run infinitely, as a loop while (true)

Comment: You can enclose all of this code in a function, if you don't want the timer variable to be available globally. That was a quick (and dirty) edit, just to illustrate the clearTimeout functionality.

Comment: @KostasX , I'm sorry, I had not seen the first line

Comment: @KostasX, global it is perfectly, the function is called again each that I click on the button, creating many functions, There is some method to validate?

Comment: what is the best technique for doing this? $(document).on("click", ".upvotes", function(){ .... or $('.upvotes').on("click", fuction()...?

Comment: I think this [article section](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) will clear things up for you a little bit. It depends on many factors. In your case, I think document.on is the right choice.

Comment: Thanks again, seriously!!